# .htaccess IP whitelist is being ignored

Tags: htaccess, wordpress

I have the following in my .htaccess file to only allow access from a block of IP's and everyone else is being redirected:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/custom-page.php$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111.\111\.111\.111
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^222\.222\.222\.222
RewriteRule $ custom-page.php [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

For some reason the IP's that are on the whitelist are still getting redirected to the custom-page.php

Comment: Just a few thoughts so if I assume too much or too little, please forgive me. You do know that `!` is NOT. Just making sure. You are not using `$` to signify the end of the string. When comparing IP addresses, leading 0's should be removed. You are not using `[OR]` at the end of the RewrtieCond lines. I suggest `[NC,OR]` for the custom page line. As well, if there are params for the custom page, then you want to change the `$` with `.*$`. For RewriteRule, change `$` to `.*`.  See if that works. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc regarding 'When comparing IP addresses, leading 0's should be removed.'. If ip is 50.110.13.0 which zeros do I take out?

Comment: The IP 50.110.13.0 is perfectly valid, however, `0`50.110.`0`13.`00`0 would not be. Some code elements strip the leading 0's and others do not so that when you compare using .htaccess (most of the time if not all of the time) you just have to remember to simply drop the leading 0's. I have made the mistake of cutting and pasting without regard to the leading 0's and worse yet, done so in writing PERL code too! Ooopppsss!

Comment: I will be in and out today, but let me know how this goes for you. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc still not working...might have to just bite the bullet and get a plugin which I hate doing.

Comment: To be honest, that may be a simpler solution. I do not know any of the CMS such as WP so I cannot help you there. Sorry. Just check out any plug-ins here https://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/search?execution=e2s1 to make sure there is no known vulnerabilities or other avoidable issues. Cheers!!

Comment: Do you have other code (specifically a `RewriteBase` directive) elsewhere in your .htaccess file? It's just that the code - as posted - would result in an invalid redirect. There might also be conflicts with existing code. Do you actually see the `302` in the network traffic? If you've previously experimented with 301 redirects then these will have been cached by the browser - so the browser cache must be cleared. Otherwise, the code looks OK, and should not be redirecting the whitelisted IPs. (Although you are missing the `$` anchor on the IPs and miss-escaped the `1` in the first IP.)

Comment: When checking exact IPs, it's a little easier to use the `=` operator (exact string match - not a regex). eg. `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=111.111.111.111`. You mention "a plugin" - a plugin for what? Do you have any other .htaccess files, in sub directories, that also use mod_rewrite? What version of Apache?

Comment: Thanks for all of your suggestions fellas. I just ended up having WP Engine implement everything on nginx level.